# Tips and tricks to improve signal of a low yield sample in FTIR spectroscopy?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, spectroscopy

I am working on donor spectroscopy in Si. Due to low donor concentration around 10^16 cm-3, the PL signal I get by exciting 670 nm pump is very low, below noise floor. The system is locked-in already. Is there any other tricks you can share that you use for FTIR spectroscopy. I use Nicolet 8700 FTIR spectrometer with an external PL setup. The samples are in a cryostat and cooled with Liquid Helium.

Comment: Can you cut the sample and use total internal reflection?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Your question gains clarity, if you would (a) use less abbreviations, (b) less slang -- "is locked in" instead of "using a lock-in amplifier" -- and (c) if you take a look at MathJax.

Comment: Thanks, I will heed your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a non-locked-in measurement (just subtracting the background from a separate measurement with pump off)? I have had success with this. In fact, if your detector and emitter are similar temperatures, and your optical system is good, then there shouldn’t be much blackbody background anyway. Other than that, switching to a more sensitive detector or increasing your pump power (or improving the emitted light collection efficiency—have you thought about the optics?), there’s not a whole lot else to do without changing your sample.